# EF Migrations - should an initial migration be automatically generated?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project that uses EF code-first. It has automatically generated a DB from the model.

Now, I want to enable EF migrations.

The ['Getting Started' docs on EF Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) suggest that in this scenario (DB already exists), two things should happen when calling `Enable-Migrations`:

1. the project gets updated with a Configuration.cs file (yup)
2. an initial migration (corresponding to the current state of the DB) should be created (didn't happen).

This is the direct link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#enabling

I don't get any initial migration when running the `Enable-Migrations` command.

Am I doing something wrong or is the documentation incorrect ?

Comment: Try "add-migration Initial".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398.aspx#option1). You need to run these two commands:

> 1. Run the `Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges` command in
>      Package Manager Console. This creates an empty migration with the
>      current model as a snapshot.
> 2. Run the `Update-Database` command in Package Manager Console. This
>      will apply the *InitialCreate* migration to the database. Since the
>      actual migration doesn’t contain any changes, it will simply add a
>      row to the `__MigrationsHistory` table indicating that this migration
>      has already been applied.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:
Add-Migration InitialCreation